# Modelling organic customer growth

Tags: exponential-function, curves

I'm currently making a model of a start-up company with the goal of describing the number of customers the company has at a given year (variable t).

These are the assumptions:

- The company has 15 customers year 1. (variable a)
- On average, each existing customer invites 2 friends their first year who then also become customers. (variable r)

I've used $c(t)=ar^t$ to describe the number of customers c at time t.

**The problem**

The problem with the function is that eventually there will be more customers than there are people on this planet. So I want to add customer population as a variable, putting a limit on how much it can grow.

I think the more accurate representation would be an S-shaped curve but I don't have the mathematical knowledge to represent this as a function.

So, how can I account for the fact that there is a limited number in the customer population?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logistic function to model customer growth with the limitation of a maximum population. The general formula for a logistic function is:

$\displaystyle f(x)={\frac {L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_{0})}}}$

Where:

- x_0 = value of the sigmoid's midpoint;
- L = the curve's maximum value;
- k = the logistic growth rate or steepness of the curve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can visit the Logistic functions wikipedia page to learn more at this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: Thats really helpful!
Do you know of an alternative function where you can input the y-intercept (15)?
Also, steepness, is that the slope at the sigmoids midpoint?